Шаблон проектирования "Стратегия" на практике
В последнее время очень заинтересовался шаблонами проектирования. Даже шпаргалку для себя составил (извините, что ссылаюсь на свой же сайт). Просто для наглядности. По мере изучения - вроде бы всё прозрачно и понятно. Но практика просто "убивает".
Очень заинтересовал паттерн "Стратегия". И вот я решил его как-то попытаться применить. Нашел, как я думаю, прикладное применение. Хочется этим инструментом порешать задачу.
Суть в следующем. Есть онлайн-игра "Forge of Empires". Одной из "проблем" которой - есть оптимальное размещение сущностей. Далее чуть подробно.
1.В игре есть игровое поле, сформированное областями-квадратами с количеством ячеек 4x4
Пример:

Игровое поле, как правило, "не имеет пустот".
2.В игре есть "сущности" разной геометрии, например, 1x1, 2x2, 3x4, 7x5 & etc.
Которые нужно оптимально разместить на поле игры так, чтобы оставшаяся область была максимальной по площади. Это цель
3.В игре некоторые сущности обязательно должны соседствовать с другими типами сущностей
Как пример, некоторые сущности "объекты" должны соседствовать с сущностями "путь". Это условие
4.Сущности "путь" должны быть непрерывны от точки назначения
На рисунке выше - это зелёная область. Это условие
5.Сущности "путь" могут иметь геометрию 1x1, 2x2.
Это условие
6.Сущности "объекты" могут иметь условие (а могут и не иметь)
Должны граничить с сущностями "путями" размером не менее 2x2, или не менее 1x1, или вовсе не обязательно граничить.

Но вот вроде бы и все рамки условий ограничений. Честно говоря, мне на ум приходит просто полный перебор. Но это самое очевидное и самое тупое решение. И самое затратное.
НО ТУТ "стратегией" даже и не пахнет!

Прошу тех, кто хорошо "качает" стратегии - просто расписать, как мне решить данную проблему в рамках сабжа. Ну или хотя бы просто набор "направлений" куда смотреть и чего копать.

Стоит убрать лишнее из вопроса (вопрос же не о паттернах, а об алгоритме схожем с плотной упаковкой) и оставить только сам вопрос об оптимальном размещении сущностей с известными ограничениями.

"Стратегия" будет нужна только если вы будете делать семейство решателей с разными характеристиками и потом выбирать лучгее из решений, например.

В этом вопросе каждый тип сущностей имеет свои требования, и свои ограничения - соответственно должен иметь своего решателя или решателей. Мне бы не хотелось разрывать вопрос на два - алгоритм отдельно, а стратегии отдельно. Суть вопроса - применение на практике! Теории не нужно.

Применять паттерны ради применения паттернов плохая затея. Лучше сначала решите без них, а хатем уже посмотрите, нужны ли они в вашем случае в этой задаче или нет. Успехов!

Мне не важно решение именно этой задачи! Она была приведена как пример сложной задачи. Ну если я заменю ее какой-нибудь другой? Мне нужны примеры применения паттернов на сложных задачах. Ну, честное слово, я лучше вас знаю, что мне нужно. Просто поверьте.

Для практики паттерна лучше выбрать задачу попроще, и с известными вариантами решений. Например поиск пути и реализации BFS, A*, HPA, итд. Чтобы бороться с одной сложностью (реализацией паттерна), а не с несколькими сразу (новая предметная область, неизвестные алгоритмы, паттерн).
